# Sending Group Keys over network

Tags: encryption

For multicast encryption one user creates group keys on his local (Symetric and asymetric).

If we encrypt these with other group user's public keys and send over networks .

Is this acceptable?

Can we say that this is equivalent to send anything with public key over network?

Is this a used method for multicast encryption.

Comment: This would often be called hybrid encryption and is common when sending data to multiple receivers. PGP / GPG behaves that way by default.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are describing a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

As Natanael mentioned, [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) and [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) use the [OpenPGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPGP) message format (RFC 4880) by default.
OpenPGP is a hybrid encryption system.
As far as I know, OpenPGP is the most commonly used format used today for email that is end-to-end encrypted. It supports efficiently sending the same plaintext message to many different recipients, more-or-less like multicast.

I don't know any better method for multicast encryption than hybrid encryption.

The original question uses the term "group key", which doesn't seem to match up with anything in OpenPGP.
However, I hear that several [group key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/group_key) protocols have been developed for pay [television encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/television_encryption) systems, such as
["Multicast Encryption: How to maintain secrecy in large, dynamic groups?"](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Espanjwan/multicast.html);
["An efficient and secure group key management scheme supporting frequent key updates on Pay-TV systems"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6077025);
and
[RFC 2023: "Group Key Management Protocol (GKMP) Specification"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2093).

[WPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) also uses group keys.

Entire books have been written about this topic, such as ["High Performance Group Key Management: A Way to scalable Internet Television"](https://books.google.com/books?id=l5BlLgEACAAJ)